# RVM's auto-detect Ruby version via repo files feature is not working in VSCode login shell terminal

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rvm

RVM has a feature to detect and use the correct Ruby version based on e.g. a `.ruby-version` file in the repo. This requires a login shell which I have enabled in VSCode via:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "bash",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["--login"],
```

However the feature isn't working by default, I have to `cd .` every time I open the terminal as if it is not a login shell.

There's a similar issue about new tabs in a gnome shell: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2519

I wonder if anyone else ran into this and whether this might be an issue with VSCode or RVM?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work by default is because rvm hooks the cd command in the shell to setup the ruby/gem paths for your project and there's no cd issued to the shell by the VS Code terminal opening.

I was able to resolve this issue on my Linux system by adding the login setup as suggested in the question and then adding a simple `cd .` at the end of my ~/.bash_profile after the section where RVM is actually set up.

Doing this results in rvm properly adjusting the paths in the VS Code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a workaround..

Add this in vs
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
"cd ."
],

Comment: `/bin/bash cd .: No such file or directory` I believe that option is to pass arguments to the shell, not to run commands.